How do I get the data in the speciified region defining a java BufferedImage.getSubimage?
I have the following code extracting a sub-image from a JAVA BufferedImage (8-bit grayscale):
// create BufferImage from original image (480px x 400px)
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(origImage.getWidth(), origImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
// fill BufferImage with bytes array from original image
img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), origBytes);

// Crop BufferedImage by range of interest (e.g. 100 x 50 px)
BufferedImage roiSubImage = img.getSubimage(roiLimits[0], roiLimits[2], roiLimits[1], roiLimits[3]);

// convert cropped image back to byte array
DataBufferByte croppedBuffer = (DataBufferByte) roiSubImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer();

byte[] outputBytes = croppedBuffer.getData();

Now - the data in outputBytes are the same as in origImage (as can be expected by the documentation of BufferedImage.getSubImage.).
How can I get the byte array representing only the cropped area of interest, i.e. the 5000 bytes in the area if interest?

I fail to see how outputBytes is not precisely the are of interest you refer to...

I think OP is saying, outputBytes is the whole image, because the sub image doesn't copy anything. It's lenght is 193000 instead of 5000.

I am confused myself. But outputBbytes has the same length as origBytes. In addition to that, the documentation of BufferedImage.getSubImage says: "The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image."

@WolfiG what do you think about creating a new buffered image and then drawing the original buffered image into it? Instead of using subImage?

Or from your Raster you can use getDataElements

Yes, I see. I can understand why data is shared but it seems odd that there's no delineation at all between the properties of image and sub image.  getDataElements could well be a way to go

@g00se I'd guess it's for memory's sake...I/O can be quite expensive...

Thanks to the comments to my post, I found the solution:
// create BufferImage from original image (480px x 400px)
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(origImage.getWidth(), origImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
// fill BufferImage with bytes array from original image
img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), origBytes);

Rectangle roi = new Rectangle(roiLimits[0], roiLimits[2], roiLimits[1], roiLimits[3]);
byte[] outBytes = (DataBufferByte) img.getData(roi).getDataBuffer().getData();

